# Grafana Chained variables with Infinity data source displays only first item in the collection variable. Can someone please assist?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Collectionlookup gives only the first list item in the variables. Other list items are not getting displayed with this plugin. Example - `CollectionLookup(xyz,6878,abcd,11328,$Application)` gives  6878,none. This does not display other item(11328). Can someone please help?

Tried from here - https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/template-variables/

Thanks
Harini

Comment: This is working now. In the Variables preview, it does not show all values. But it does reflect in the dashboard. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `CollectionLookup` will return single value depending on value of the last parameter (`$Application` in this case).

Based on your comment I assume you expected to see in preview values `6878` and `11328`, but have seen only first one.

If this is the case, I believe it is normal behavior for variable of this type: calculation of variable happens outside of Grafana's scope, and after it calculated Grafana presented with single value - correct for value of `$Application` at the moment.

To see other values try to change value of `$Application` before editing current variable.